# Flask-Login | TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, typeerror, flask-login

I am trying to create login and registration page using Flask-Login module.
Application is able to add user details to the database (sqlite) and hash the password but it is unable to properly log-in user.

Appering error is: "TypeError: object supporting the buffer API required"

Mentioned error seems to be related to "check_password_hash" method in my code.

Please find piece of my code:

a) Registration

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(form.password.data, method='sha256')
        new_user = User(username=form.username.data, password=hashed_password, email=form.email.data)
        db.create_all()
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('register_ok.html', form=form)
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

b) Login (which is not working)

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form.password):
                login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            return render_template('err_login.html')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

Could you please advise the possible fix ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Error concerned werkzeug.security module instead of flask_login.
I have fixed this already by adding user_loader:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)
```

Cheers!